# Python printing character-by-character in OSX Terminal

Tags: python, terminal, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to have Python copy the contents of a .txt file into the bash terminal on OS X (10.10), but the line does not print until every single character of the line has been printed to the line. Is there any way to have Python print each line character-by-character, instead of line-by-line? My code is designed to wait between characters, but each line simply takes a long time to print:

```
while True:
    character = text_file.read(1)
    if not character: break
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(character)
        time.sleep(0.050)
```

When I run this code in IDLE, the characters print one at a time. In Terminal, lines take several seconds to print, and each line prints all at once. Is there any way to reproduce the behavior I'm seeing in IDLE in Terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `sys.stdout.flush()` after `sys.stdout.write(character)`

The reason should be that the output of stdout is buffered.

Comment: Perfect. I hadn't thought of that. I'm guessing that IDLE just doesn't have a buffer for stdout, then. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

if you want remove new line at the end of the line.

you can simply

```
print character,
```

will remove the new line(\n).